# What is the usage of the method Activity.startNextMatchingActivity(Intent)?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

The API says "You can use this to hand the Intent off to the next Activity that can handle it. ".But we can use startActivity(getIntent()) to do that too.What are the diffirences?

Comment: What SilentKnight did is an excellent example of what you should do. [http://developer.android.com/index.html] is the official site for Android developers to reference with questions or for updates on the field of Android development. ALOT of your questions will be answered on the developer site in the documentation or you can just look it up online and find the docs there. They do a great job of making things as easy to find and clear as possible. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at what the doc says:

```
startNextMatchingActivity
```

> Special version of starting an activity, for use when you are
>   replacing other activity components. You can use this to hand the
>   Intent off to the next Activity that can handle it. You typically call
>   this in onCreate(Bundle) with the Intent returned by getIntent().

**Parameters**

*intent*    The intent to dispatch to the next activity. For correct behavior, this must be the same as the Intent that started your own activity; the only changes you can make are to the extras inside of it.

*options*   Additional options for how the Activity should be started. See Context.startActivity(Intent, Bundle) for more details.

**Returns**

> Returns a boolean indicating whether there was another Activity to
>   start: true if there was a next activity to start, false if there
>   wasn't. In general, if true is returned you will then want to call
>   finish() on yourself.